# SQL function that returns 0 when no records returned from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the below function to return Total Sales for a particular year, month and Territory entered as inputs. But I need to return 0 if there are no sales for the input parameters. I tried the IFNULL function but it does not seem to work.

```
Create Function GetTotalSales(@Year int,@month int,@TerritoryID int)
Returns Table
As
    Return (Select Sum(TotalDue) as TotalSales, Cast(OrderDate AS DATE) as OrderDate, TerritoryID       
            From AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderheader
            Where @Year=DATEPART(Year,OrderDate) and @month=DATEPART(Month,OrderDate) and @TerritoryID=TerritoryID  
            Group By OrderDate, TerritoryID
           );
Go
```

Comment: If `TotalDue` is constrained to be not null, then you should be able to write `ifnull(sum(TotalDue), 0)`. If you wrote `sum(ifnull(TotalDue,0))`, then of course it would not work. It all depends upon whether you can infer `sum(TotalDue) is null` to mean that no rows were found. If you cannot rely on that, then you do indeed have to do something more complicated. But you also might want to consider the possible edge case that the sum of sales could exist and be zero. If such an edge case is not to be considered, then returning 0 is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can express this in a single query as:

```
with r as (
      Select Sum(TotalDue) as TotalSales, Cast(OrderDate AS DATE) as OrderDate, TerritoryID       
      From AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderheader
      Where @Year = DATEPART(Year, OrderDate) and @month = DATEPART(Month, OrderDate) and @TerritoryID = TerritoryID  
      Group By OrderDate, TerritoryID
     )
select *
from r
union all
select TotalSales, OrderDate, TerritoryId
from (select 0 as TotalSales, NULL as OrderDate, @TerritoryId as TerritoryId
     ) x
where not exists (select 1 from r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider an approach like the following. By constructing a table with a single "default" row and then unconditionally left-joining to it, we ensure that the results always contain at least one row.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetTotalSales(@year INT, @month INT, @territoryID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(TotalSales, 0) AS TotalSales
        ,OrderDate
        ,TerritoryID

    FROM
        (VALUES (0)) AS default_values(default_value) 

    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(TotalDue)               AS TotalSales
            ,CAST(OrderDate AS DATE)    AS OrderDate
            ,TerritoryID

        FROM 
            AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderheader

        WHERE 
            (@year=DATEPART(Year,OrderDate))
            AND 
            (@month=DATEPART(Month,OrderDate))
            AND
            (@territoryID=TerritoryID)

        GROUP BY 
            OrderDate, TerritoryID

    ) AS source_data
    ON (1=1)
);
```